# Who has a higher chance of drawing an easy question?

Tags: probability, statistics

From a pool of N questions n are easy. Two people draw a question without returning it. Who has a higher chance of drawing an easy question?

Comment: Everyone has the same probability of drawing an easy question, whether she draws first, last, or in between.

Comment: Do the two persons draw the questions simultaneously or sequentially?

Comment: Is $N\ge 2$? If the pool runs out of questions so the second person doesn't get one, that changes things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume $N\geq 2$

$P($First person draw an easy question$)=\frac{n}{N}$

$P($First person draw a hard question$)=1-\frac{n}{N}=\frac{N-n}{N}$

$P($Second person draw an easy question$)=\frac{n}{N}\cdot \frac{n-1}{N-1}+\frac{N-n}{N}\cdot \frac{n}{N-1}=\frac{Nn-n}{N(N-1)}=\frac{n}{N}$

So their chances are equal.

Answer (score 1):

You don’t actually need to make any calculations to answer the question.

The two questions drawn form a random sample of two questions from the pool of $N$ questions. Using $E$ to denote an easy question and $H$ to denote a hard question, we can distinguish four types of sample: $EE,EH,HE$, and $HH$. The first person gets an easy question if the sample is of type $EE$ or $EH$; the second person gets an easy question if it’s of type $EE$ or $HE$. There are exactly as many samples of type $EH$ as there are of type $HE$, so the first and second persons are equally likely to get an easy question.